# Highcharts: Is there a way to pull different api from HighCharts Rangefinder buttons?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to create a candlestick chart with Coingecko API and Highcharts.  The problem is the API sends out different timelines depending on the range you are trying to pull.  So if I pull 1 day it'll give me hours, but if I pull max it separates it into 4 day increments for ohlc.  With only a zoom feature pulling max data, the chart looks terrible under 6 months.  I tried adding event handlers to the range selector buttons like this:

```
rangeSelector: {
  inputBoxWidth: '55px',
  selected: 1,
  buttons: [{
    type: 'day',
    count: 1,
    text: '1d',
    event: {
      function(e) {
        setTime(1);
        setVolTime(1);
      }
    }
  }, {
    type: 'day',
    count: 7,
    text: '7d',
    event: {
      function(e) {
        setTime(7);
        setVolTime(7);
      }
    }
  },
```

But it won't allow you to click on the buttons if no data is present.  I also tried setting extremes on the X axis like so:

```
xAxis: {
  events: {
    setExtremes: function(e) {
      if(typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton)!== 'undefined') {
        var c = e.rangeSelectorButton.count;
        var t = e.rangeSelectorButton.type;
        var btn_index = null;
        if(c == 1 && t == "day"){
          btn_index = 0;
        } else if(c == 7 && t == "day"){
          btn_index = 1;
        } else if(c == 1 && t == "month"){
          btn_index = 2;
        } else if(c == 6 && t == 'month'){
          btn_index = 3;
        } else if(c == 1 && t == "year"){
          btn_index = 4;
        } else if(t == "all"){
          btn_index = 5;
        }
        if (btn_index === 0) {
          setTime(1)
          setVolTime(1)
        } else if (btn_index === 1) {
          setTime(30)
          setVolTime(14)
        } else if (btn_index === 2) {
          setTime(30)
          setVolTime(30)
        } else if (btn_index === 3) {
          setTime(180)
          setVolTime('max')
        } else if (btn_index === 4) {
          setTime(365)
          setVolTime('max')
        } else if (btn_index === 5) {
          setTime('max')
          setVolTime('max')
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

However that also doesn't allow the rangefinder buttons to be clickable without all 365 days of data being present. For example the rangefinder defaults on page load to 7 day, only 1 day and 7 day buttons are 'clickable'.  Even clicking the 1 day button doesn't change the state from 7 days to one day.  So after going through Highcharts forums and trying some of the possible solutions I posted here, I tried contacting support and was redirected here to Stack Overflow.  As always any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to put other API to Highcharts inside rangeSelector events, for example when you fetch data.

```
rangeSelector: {
  buttons: [{
    type: 'month',
    count: 1,
    text: '1m',
    events: {
      click: function() {
        // The Endpoint URL
        let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
        fetch(url)
          .then(function(response) {
            // Render the Response Status
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = response.status;
            // Parse the body as JSON
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(json) {
            // Render the parsed body
            document.getElementById('result_json').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json);
          })
      }
    }
  }, {
    type: 'month',
    count: 3,
    text: '3m'
  }, {
    type: 'month',
    count: 6,
    text: '6m'
  }, {
    type: 'ytd',
    text: 'YTD'
  }, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 1,
    text: '1y'
  }, {
    type: 'all',
    text: 'All'
  }]
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5agsvnL1/

Comment: Hey Sebastian, thanks for your update.  I have tried the approach you sent as well as having the fetch directly setState to my useEffect function.  I set up a sandbox here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-pond-of2rcr?file=/src/components/CoinPage/Charts/CandleStickChart.js)

Comment: Besides that I was also wondering if there was a better way to set my volume chart.  I'm currently splitting it into two arrays so I can set up and down color, and I feel it's incorrectly displaying the results.  So the question about that would be, is there a better way to color the ups and downs of the volume bar chart than how I approached it?

Comment: I should've added, the volume charts runs 2 different column charts in it with data from the 2 arrays.  So ideally not splitting the data would allow me to keep in one column chart with the up and down colors.  upColor did not work for that as it did with the candlestick chart.

Comment: Setting the color inside the series seems to be a good option, but if you want to change the colors inside one series you can try using the [series.column.zones](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.zones).